# Got a strange $ 1 2 3 output in macOS Shell

Tags: macos, shell

I typed  `echo $ ?` and got

```
$ 1 2 3
```

Normally I should get a `$ ?`, so I opened a new shell, typed `echo $ ?` in and my output was

```
$ ?
```

I tried to trigger it, and some times it was `$ 1 2 3` and some times  `$ ?`. It only happens in the classic shell, in the iTerm shell it works fine. I'm using macOS High Sierra version 10.13.4.

Why is the output wrong and how to trigger it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$` by itself has no special meaning.

The `?` is a *one character wildcard*. (In comparison, `*` is a multi-character wildcard.) `?` is replaced by any files in your current working directory which consist of a single character. When you see `1 2 3` as output, do an `ls` and you'll find those listed as files in your directory.

```
$ echo ?
?
$ touch 1
$ echo ?
1
$ touch 2
$ echo ?
1 2
$ ls
1
2
```